# Find integer solution.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

$1! + 2! + ... + n! = k^3 + 6$ , find positive integers   $n$ and $k$  satisfying the above equation.

Here I have approached this problem for $n \lt 5$ and got one of the solutions as $n = 4 , k = 3$, but for $n \gt 5$ all I can conclude is , that $k$ should be $3$ modulo $30$ , but this is not helping in finding integer solutions for $n \gt 5$ . Please suggest an approach.

Comment: Use mathjax to write mathematical expressions, here is a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Are you aware of the $\Gamma$(Gamma) function and the subfactorial function? If yes then you can use them to find the solutions for $n$ and $k$

Comment: For $n\ge 5$ left-hand-side is divisible by $9$, but right-hand-side ..?..

Comment: @Catalan I outlined my solution below, You can check it easily

Comment: @Algebrology No need for such complex concepts. Easy mod can guarantee the solution

Answer (score 4):

From the well-known properties, we can prove that $x^3$ can give remainders $0, 1, 6$ in mod $7$. Therefore, $k^3 + 6$ will yield $6, 5, $ or $0$ in mod $7$. Checking the small cases, you will find that $n$ can't be greater than $7$ due to the inapplicability of $1! + ... + 6!$ for the mentioned remainders. Small cases can be checked easily.

**Update**: Although mod $7$ could give identity relations when $n \geq 7$ is considered, other users have suggested considering mod $13$ since it holds almost the same properties with $7$ only with more base cases and proving the inapplicability of $n \geq 13$ via obtaining $1! + 2! + ... + 12!$ different from above values.

Comment: $1!+2!+..+6! = 873 \equiv 5 \bmod 7$

Comment: Good. The idea of @Oleg in the comments, about divisibility by nine, is perhaps even simpler.

Comment: @Snowflake  for n > 6 , there is a possibility that both left and right hand side is 5 modulo 7 , so how can we say that we don't have solution for n greater than 7

Comment: While mod 7 does not work, the same argument does work modulo 13 (though the non-prime 9 is much easier as already pointed out)